# Remove 'component has been registered but not used' in eslint for Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, eslint

I am implementing dynamic components where I use:

`<component :is="component_name"></component>`

However, eslint keeps returning this:

> 60:16  error  The "component" component has been registered but not used
> vue/no-unused-components

How can I disable the rule above on eslint?

Answer (score 12):

You can disable that particular ESLint rule by writing the following at the top of your JavaScript file: `/* eslint-disable vue/no-unused-components */`. Note that this may be after the first `<script>` tag in a single-file component (ie. a `.vue` file).

In your situation, however, you may find it more useful to just disable this error for a particular line by appending the following to the end of the problematic line causing the error: `// eslint-disable-line vue/no-unused-components`.

Comment: This is really useful when dynamically adding/removing components. Thanks!